# MySql connection not closing in php on window server

Tags: php, mysql

Our server is facing "Internal Server Error 500" problem and we think it is related to the mysql connection not closing. Mysql connection not closing despite connection close code written in each page.

Below is code the for connection opening & close:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'akaj@32';
    $dbname = 'mydb_new';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if($conn) { mysql_close($conn);}
```

Can any one help?

Comment: "and we thing it is related to mysql connection not closing." - Exactly how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: is there any info in the error-log of your http-server?

Comment: and/or in the mysql log? see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

Comment: Even if the MySQL connection is not closing the number of concurrent connections allowed is usually high enough that you'll never reasonably reach it by just testing on a development machine. On the other hand if this is happening on a live server maybe this limit is too small to facilitate all concurrent users.

Comment: Why there are so many newbies coming like from same factory using `mysql_*` instead of `mysqli_*`